# Initialize Spring Boot test beans before tested Application

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

Given a Spring Boot application that does something on start that needs a mock server:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    System.err.println("should be 2nd: application init (needs the mock server)");
  }

  public boolean doSomething() {
    System.err.println("should be 3rd: test execution");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Therefore, the mock server should be initialized beforehand:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class ApplicationITest {

  @Autowired
  MockServer mockServer;

  @Autowired
  Application underTest;

  @BeforeAll
  void setUpInfrastructure() {
    mockServer.init();
  }

  @Test
  void doSomething() {
    assertTrue(underTest.doSomething());
  }
}

@Component
class MockServer {
  void init() {
    System.err.println("should be 1st: mock server init");
  }
}
```

But the application seems to be initialized always first:

```
should be 2nd: application init (needs the mock server)
should be 1st: mock server init
should be 3rd: test execution
```

How can I get those to be executed in the intended order?

I tried using `Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` and `@AutoConfigureBefore` with no success.

Comment: By not doing it like this... The application context is started before the test class infra is being called. So `@BeforeAll` is called after the context started. If you need the `init` called before that annotate it with `@PostConstruct` so that it is part of the bean lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this would be the accepted answer. Why don't you write it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how it works. How would the test be able to call a method on an `@Autowired` instance without the application context being started? That simply is not how it works, hence the result you see.

However as you just want to call an method after the object has been constructed mark the method with `@PostConstruct`. With this the `init` method will be called as soon as the `MockServer` instance has been created and got everything injected.

Comment: Regarding your first remark: "without the application context being started" was not a necessity. The application context could be started, only the `ApplicationReadyEvent` should be triggered after the mock server initialization.

Comment: Which it will be if everything is part of the application context lifecycle. You tried to execute the `init` in a test infra method. Which requires the `MockServer` to be injected, which requires a full appliocation context. The startup isn't a multi phase thing in which you can do things at moments you like (you have some control with the `@PostConstruct` and some special interfaces in the spring framework, but that is it).

Comment: Thanks again, my key to understanding was that application and test use the _same_ Spring context (which is logical since one can `@Autowire Application underTest`). Following this, an alternative to `@PostConstruct` would be to initialize the mock server with `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` (just like the application) and let it have an `Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`.